# Jinja2 + SQL - How to pass a list of columns to use in a macro

Tags: python, sql, jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to create some data sanity checks for random integrations. To do so I need to create queries that are flexible enough to be run in different tables. I'm using jinja2 to create some macros so I can pass columns and tables to those queries. Now my problem is if I want to check for duplicate data-points, in all columns like:

```
SELECT username, email, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY username, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I would need to create a macro that allowed me to pass multiple columns to select statement and i don't know how to get it. I was wondering if I could create a .yaml with the table name + columns and make a macro that would fetch that data

For now I have this working

```
 {%- macro duplicates_ids(table, column) -%}
    select{{ column }}
    ,count(*)
    from {{ table }}
    group by {{ column }}
    having count(*) >1
    {%- endmacro -%}
```

So then I can just define the table name and the column to test the table.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: first concatenate the column and pass it to the macro

Comment: Are you using DBT for this? If yes, add that context.

Comment: no, i don't have dbt! found a short term solution, have the macro in my main.py file and after i pass the columns concatenated i write it back to the .sql file and run it. not sure how to do it other way